# Removing outer parentheses of a string not working

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to search a string with a value and then get the value I want and then search for it again until I find nothing else.

All did run well until a part of my code where i remove the outer parentheses of my string does not execute what I want. It does not give an error, it simply does nothing.

To summarize:

`valGrep = "lights"`

`SecVal = "#define lights()(broad())"`

What I'm trying to do is set TempGrep = broad(), but until the end of the function it is still (broad()) , the parentheses still exists.

This is my code. I put comment 'This is the part where it does not work - on the line not working

```
Sub SearchExt()

Dim FirstAddress As String
Dim MyArr As Variant
Dim Rng As Range
Dim Rcount As Long
Dim I As Long
Dim TempGrep As String

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = False
    .EnableEvents = False
End With

' Fill in the search Value
MyArr = Array(valGrep)

With Sheets("Extension").UsedRange

    Rcount = 0

    For I = LBound(MyArr) To UBound(MyArr)

        ' If you use LookIn:=xlValues it will also work with a
        ' formula cell that evaluates to tmpAnaly
        ' Note : I use xlPart in this example and not xlWhole
        Set Rng = .Find(What:=MyArr(I), _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlFormulas, _
                        LookAt:=xlPart, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=False)
        If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
            FirstAddress = Rng.Address
            SecVal = Rng.Value
                ' get grep result
                TempGrep = Trim(Replace(SecVal, valGrep, " "))
                If InStr(SecVal, "#define") <> 0 Then
                    TempGrep = Trim(Replace(TempGrep, "#define", " "))
                End If
                ' Delete comment
                If InStr(1, TempGrep, "/*") <> 0 Then
                    TempGrep = Left(TempGrep, InStr(1, TempGrep, "/*") - 1)
                End If
                ' When type is included
                If InStr(1, TempGrep, "U1") <> 0 Or InStr(1, TempGrep, "U2") <> 0 Or InStr(1, TempGrep, "U4") <> 0 Or _
                InStr(1, TempGrep, "S1") <> 0 Or InStr(1, TempGrep, "S2") <> 0 Or InStr(1, TempGrep, "S4") <> 0 Then
                    searchFlg = False

                End If
                If InStr(1, TempGrep, " ") <> 0 Then
                    TempGrep = Trim(Replace(TempGrep, " ", ""))
                End If

                ' Edit the Grep result and get the value in parentheses
                TempGrep = Mid(TempGrep, 2, Len(TempGrep) - 2) 'This is the part where it does not work

                ' In the case of forced type conversion
                If InStr(1, TempGrep, "U1)") <> 0 Or InStr(1, TempGrep, "U2)") <> 0 Or InStr(1, TempGrep, "U4)") <> 0 Or InStr(1, TempGrep, "S1)") <> 0 Or _
                InStr(1, TempGrep, "S2)") <> 0 Or InStr(1, TempGrep, "S4)") <> 0 Then
                    TempGrep = Right(TempGrep, Len(TempGrep) - InStr(1, TempGrep, ")"))
                End If

            Do
                Rcount = Rcount + 1

                valGrep = TempGrep

                Set Rng = .FindNext(Rng)
            Loop While Not Rng Is Nothing And Rng.Address <> FirstAddress
        End If
    Next I
End With

With Application
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    .EnableEvents = True
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: what does this mean? `part of my code where i remove the outer parentheses`

Comment: It means it did everything I wanted until the part where for example (word()), I want to remove the outer parentheses to make it just word(). Did you get it?

Comment: Did you try setting a breakpoint on that line? What value does `TempGrep` have before and after that line?

Comment: your example is missing quotes ... should it not be `SecVal = "#define lights()(broad())"` ??

Comment: @Taosique: Yes, I tried setting a breakpoint line before and after the line. Before the line TempGrep = "(broad())"
After the line TempGrep = "(broad())"

seems the line doesnt work at all.

Comment: @jsotola: Yes you are right, sorry for the missing quotes.

Comment: put `debug.print len(tempgrep), tempgrep` before and after the failing line ... then check the immediate window after running the code. what do you get?

Comment: @jsotola, this one: 
FYI, new value for TempGrep =  (GetAppCfgLdaExists())
 36                                       (GetAppCfgLdaExists())                          
 35                                       (GetAppCfgLdaExists())                      
 36                                       (GetAppCfgLdaExists())                          
 35                                       (GetAppCfgLdaExists())

Comment: @jsotola, i ran it again and it became:  36                                       (GetAppCfgLdaExists())                          
 34                                   (GetAppCfgLdaExists()) what does this mean?

Comment: invisible characters or unicode characters. ....  put in this code before the failing line `dim i as integer`  `for i = 1 to len(TempGrep)` `debug.print asc(mid(TempGrep, i, 1))` `next i`   .... it should print the ascii value of each character

Comment: @jsotola:  9 
 9 
 9 
 9 
 9 
 9 
 9 
 40 
 71 
 101 
 116 
 65 
 112 
 112 
 67 
 102 
 103 
 76 
 100 
 97 
 69 
 120 
 105 
 115 
 116 
 115 
 40 
 41 
 41 
 9 
 9 
 9 
 9 
 9 
 9 
 9 what does this mean? how do i remove them, specifically the 9s

Comment: `TempGrep = Replace(TempGrep, Chr(9), "")`

Comment: the ascii 9 is a TAB character  ... do another replace `Replace(TempGrep, vbTab, "")`    ..... you must be getting the data from a number of worksheet cells. (around 16 of them)

Comment: @jsotola: thanks man, now it worked. it was just a tab character that delayed me this long. thanks so much.

Comment: @Vegard: thanks for the suggestions man

Comment: @jsotola I suggest you post your inputs as an answer so the question can be marked as resolved :)

Comment: Is the object consistently wrapped in brackets with it's own set of brackets? ... If so a simple RegEx would probably be better and easier to nab it out of there... I'd opt for RegEx anyway, just it would be a complex one if not.

Answer (score 0):

@jsotola should receive credit if he posts an answer, as he is the one who solved the issue. This post is only meant to expand on the solution to the underlying problem.

As pointed out in comments by jsotola and verified by OP, the problem is invisible characters.

Your code already uses the `trim` function, which removes surplus spaces at the start and end of the given string. But this function doesn't affect spaces in the middle of a string or non-printable characters.

Using the [`clean`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/CLEAN-function-26f3d7c5-475f-4a9c-90e5-4b8ba987ba41) function however, is a good way to remove a good part of non-printables (note that it won't remove all of them). To access it, you'll use `WorksheetFunction.Clean(string)`

If you have other invisible characters, like unicode characters not covered by `clean`, there's no native way to handle these in Excel 2013 at least. Some time ago I had a similar problem and hacked together a very ugly and un-optimized (but fully functional) solution:

```
Function cleanSpecialCharacters(str As String)
    Dim spaceChars As String, bannedChars As String
    bannedChars = Chr(127) & "," & Chr(129) & "," & Chr(141) & "," & Chr(143) & "," & Chr(144) & "," & Chr(157) & "," & Chr(160)
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    spaceChars = Chr(32) & Chr(32)

    Dim tVal As String, bChar As Variant
    tVal = str

    tVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Clean(tVal)
    tVal = Application.WorksheetFunction.Trim(tVal)

    For Each bChar In Split(bannedChars, ",")
        tVal = Replace(tVal, bChar, "")
    Next

    tVal = Replace(tVal, spaceChars, Chr(32), 1)

    cleanSpecialCharacters = tVal
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Function
```

Usage: `TempGrep = cleanSpecialCharacters(TempGrep)`

Should be easy enough to modify if you have any other needs.